# Что такое "Алгоритм поиска в ширину" для графа?

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Я читаю-читаю статьи по этому вопросу, и никак не могу понять, какой должен быть результат.
Я думал, что этот алгоритм должен выдать последовательность вершин начиная с заданной, такую, чтобы обойти весь граф (побывать в каждой вершине один раз). И, собственно, то же самое от меня хочет преподаватель.
Но, видимо, это что-то другое?
Например, вот в статье ([Поиск в ширину](http://kvodo.ru/search-width.html)), со входными данными "2" получаем результат "2 3 4 1" (при этом на графе нет пути из 4 в 1).
В общем, объясните, пожалуйста?

Comment: Вот [простое и понятное описание](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83), даже с анимированными картинками.

Answer (score 3):

В ширину:

1. Выбираешь начальную вершину.
2. Затем по очереди проверяешь все соединенные с ней вершины(потомки).
3. Когда они закончатся, за начальную берешь одну из проверенных вершин (потомков).

В глубину:

1. Выбираешь начальную вершину.
2. Затем проверяешь соединенную с ней вершину(потомка) и сразу делаешь ее новой основной вершиной.
3. Если у проверенной вершины нет еще одной связи(с потомком), возвращаешься на предыдущую вершину(предка) и ищешь у нее непроверенную связь с потомкам, если такой связи к нет - снова назад(к предку).

Answer (score 2):

Мы на дискретке делали примерно так:
В очередь записывали первую точку, потом шли в алфавитном порядке во все доступные стороны и записывали точки в очередь. Когда пути из этой точки заканчивались, мы ее вычеркивали и переходили к той, которая следующая в очереди.
В данном случае (см. рисунок) записываем "a", потом пишем "b" "d" "l", пути из "a" закончились, вычеркиваем "a". Переходим к "b", из нее нет никаких путей - вычеркиваем, переходим к "d", из нее попадаем в "f", "g" - записываем. Из "d" пути закончились - вычеркиваем, переходим к l и т.д.
Примечание к рисунку:
В рисунке ошибка, когда я делал это задание, я забыл английский алфавит и посчитал, что k идет раньше, чем j. На самом деле их просто нужно поменять местами.
Пунктирной линией помечались пути, которые мы не проходим потому, что они приведут в точку которую мы уже обошли.
Жирной линией отмечен пройденный, в процессе обхода, путь.
Жирные, пунктирные линии и зачеркнутые буквы возникали в процессе обхода, их не было в изначальном задании.

[image]